# 401 (Unauthorized): Exchange 2010 SP1 cannot see Exchange 2010 SP3 free/busy data under Federation

Tags: exchange

I have followed the procedures to set up federation trust between 2 forest sites. Site A (Exchange 2010 SP1) and Site B (Exchange 2010 SP3).  They are not connected by any network.

The link to MFG seems to work by running Test-FederationTrust from both sites and we have established org relationship between the 2 sites.

However, Site B (EX2010 SP3) can see Site A (EX2010 SP1)'s free/busy data but Site A (EX2010 SP1) cannot see Site B (EX2010 SP1)'s free/busy data.

Below is the error when running Test-OrganisationRelationship from Site A (EX2010 SP1)

Site A error is **"HTTP status 401: Unauthorised"**

**VERBOSE: [07:09:06.136 GMT] Test-OrganizationRelationship : The Microsoft Exchange Autodiscover service failed to be called at 'https://autodiscover.siteB.com.au/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc/WSSecurity' because the
following error occurred: WebException.Response = 
Exception:
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.**

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

To configure free/busy sharing between two federated Exchange 2010 organizations, Check you have performed the steps in [Configure Federated Delegation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/ff601760%28v%3Dexchg.141%29) for both organizations.

Here're similar thread for your reference:

[enter link description here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/74aa0c59-e0ec-4edb-84af-af6624a72adc/exchange-2010-federation-orgrelationsship-401-unauthorized?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy)

[enter link description here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d308fd35-3a89-45fd-9b64-9accfd41bc7e/exchange-2010-federation-between-2-sites-both-generates-errors?forum=exchange2010)